# HighCharts not plotting data coming from model method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to plot some data coming from rails SQLite tables. I have a function that sits in a model which goes like this:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:my_format] = '%a, %d %b %Y'
        arr = []
        a = 1
        b = 100
        for i in a...b
            tweet = Bla.find(i)
            if tweet.sentiment == "p"
              x = 5
            else
              x = 1
            end
            d = tweet.tweetdate.to_date

            arr << [ tweet.tweetdate.to_date.to_formatted_s(:my_format), x.to_f]
        end

        return arr
```

In my view I have a  tag where I have my HightChart object defined there. The problem is at the part where I add my data namely:

```
series: [{
            pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,

            data: <%=  Tweetsentiment.get_sentiment_data %>
        }]
```

Tweetsentiment is my model while get_sentiment_data is the function that contains the code above.

The line: **data: <%=  Tweetsentiment.get_sentiment_data %>** does not plot the data and the HighCharts does not show up at all. However, if I print the variable arr and copy the result from the console and paste it in like so:

data : [ ["Tue, 10 Sep 2013", 1], ["Tue, 10 Sep 2013", 5]]

The chart plots the data and works perfectly fine.

Why is <%=  Tweetsentiment.get_sentiment_data %> not working. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but try this:

```
Tweetsentiment.get_sentiment_data.to_json.html_safe
```

i.e

```
series: [{
            pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,

            data: <%=  Tweetsentiment.get_sentiment_data.to_json.html_safe %>
        }]
```